# access to variables in nested functions in php

Tags: php

suppose i have two nested function like this :

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function test(){
    $b  =   20;
    function Sum()
    {   
        $b  =   $GLOBALS['a']   +   $b;
    }
}
test();
Sum();
echo $b;
```

now i want in function Sum() access to $b variable declared in function test();
How do you do?

Comment: It is not right to nest functions like this in PHP. What you want to do has become possible in PHP 5.3 but I'm not sure it's really what you need

Comment: this example do not certain task. this is just an example for that how to get $b declared in test() function in sum() function.

Comment: Then please provide an example/description that shows more of the actual use-case. Nesting function definitions like in the current example does nothing to the variable visibility, `function Sum` is declared and defined in the global scope just like `function test` is, the definition is only "postponed" until `function test` is executed. With php 5.3 (as Pekka has mentioned)  lambda functions/closures have been introduced. If they are what you're looking for depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Use `return`-statements instead of globals. `$b = sum($a, 20);` could work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wild-Guessing-mode:
Your function `Sum()` would "normaly" take two parameters/operands like

```
function Sum($a, $b) {  
  return $a+$b;
}
echo Sum(1, 20);
```

Now you have the function Test() and you want it to return a **function** *fn* that takes only one parameter and then calls Sum($a, $b) with one "pre-defined" parameter and the one passed to *fn*.

That's called either currying or partial application (depending on what exactly you implement) and you can do something like that with [lambda functions/closures](http://docs.php.net/functions.anonymous) since php 5.3

```
<?php
function Sum($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

function foo($a) {
    return function($b) use ($a) {
        return Sum($a, $b);
    };
}

$fn = foo(1) // -> Sum(1, $b);
$fn = foo(2) // -> Sum(2, $b);
echo $fn(47);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this?

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function test(){
    $b = Sum(20);
}

function Sum($value)
{   
    $value = $GLOBALS['a'] + $value;
    return $value;
}

test();
// Sum(); // Why do you need this here??
echo $b;
```

#### Edit: Better without globals

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum($value1, $value2)
{   
    return $value1 + $value2;
}

$b = 20; // you could call Sum($a, 20); instead
$b = Sum($a, $b);
echo $b;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Context best way is to pass the variable to the function like this

`Sum($b)`

But if you are looking for an alternative then you can use closures
but REMEMBER PHP<5.3 does not support closures

You can do

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function test() {
   $b  =   20;
   function Sum() use($b)
   {   
      $b  =   $GLOBALS['a']   +   $b;
  }
}
test();
Sum();
echo $b;
```